# w3m specify http port

Tags: w3m

When using `w3m` terminal browser, how can I specify the http/s port that I want to use when connecting to a web server.

There does not seem to be a `-p` option to use non-standard ports (80 & 443). The colon syntax, `localhost:8080` does not work either.

Anyone know how to do this? Seems like I have been able to specify the port in addition to the host on `w3m` before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use a full URL, e.g., `w3m http://localhost:8080/` works.